# VSCodium not importing modules in Python

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I wanted to make a voice assistant importing SpeechRecognition on Python;
I installed PyAudio and SpeechRecognition with the following commands: `pip install PyAudio` `pip install SpeechRecognition` on Linux, but when I try to import SpeechRecognition with `import speech_recognition as sr`, [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/#why) doesn't import the module.

But then I tried to import other modules, and the same thing happens... what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check which pip you are using through `pip --version`, and which python you are using through `where python`(cmd) or `get-command python`(PowerShell). Make sure pip matches up with the python interpreter you are using.

If it's not, you can try to reopen the terminal with the shortcut 'Ctrl+Shift+`'. And then to check the pip version again.

If it still not matches up with the interpreter. That's maybe this environment hasn't installed the pip in this environment.

Comment: @Jo_ Could you look into the update of this answer?

Comment: This is the problem, when I enter this selection, there is no option for Python 3.9.5 (remember that I'm on Linux)

Comment: @Jo_ Very sorry for that, The update is not for this answer. I just mix up it. And have you followed the early methods I suggest? And if you have met any problem, could you let me know? And if you can provide a picture of it, it will be perfect.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/g1lQ8qI.png ‍https://i.imgur.com/cYY4l2H.png

Answer (score 0):

I think its main reason is on Linux pip is for python 2 while pip3 is for python 3.
If you are using py3 using pip3 may help. Other reasons may include a virtual environment you are on.If vscodium does not automatically activate it or whatever extension you are using do not run in the virtual environment it may not find the packages you installed. you can try these commands:

Example:

```
pip3 install PyAudio
pip3 install SpeechRecognition 
python3 main.py
```

Comment: pip must NOT be pip2. It depends on you distro, config, etc. Therefore the preferred way is to use `python -m pip`. You can, of course, try pip3 and pip2, but this is not recommended.